# Please Assist in Identifying This Frame!

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, vintage

I ran across this site and thought someone may be able to easily identify this vintage racer. My neighbor passed and left it to me and I was hoping to at least know what it was. He worked on bikes for many years several decades back and raced as well. It is extremely light. Campagnolo hardware, Cinelli seat and stem. I’m thinking Cinelli but can’t find any bike with holes in the frame connections as seen. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks![image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: The frame lugs in the first image are quite unique, and should permit fairly accurate identification -- if someone here recognizes them.  Otherwise, your pictures are too narrow in scope to permit much identification.

Comment: Where are you located at? If the frame was made by a nearby build, it might help.

Comment: That paint colour was popular with Bianchi but naturally other makers could use it too.

Comment: The bike is from Atlanta Georgia if that helps. I will get some full photos and post. I went straight to the unique aspects I noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice looking frame. Some nice looking, desirable equipment attached to it too. Would be cool to see it finished off and back on the road. Probably holds more value if you keep it authentic to the era/leave as is.

The holey bits are called the frame lugs, I guess they are ‘drilled lugs’ if that helps bring up any more search results.

Possibly it’s from a big brand, or maybe from a small custom builder, made specially for your late neighbour. Either way it’s probably a quality example, someone’s gone to a bit of trouble making it.

I think the more successful searches are for a bike with original branding and equipment spec from the biggest manufacturers. Then it’s a matter of hunting for archived catalogues etc. Otherwise it’s a bit of a guessing game/luck if someone else has the same one.

But... get some more good quality pictures of the whole bike from all kinds of angles and keep asking around on various websites, maybe you’ll start picking up clues. I think it’s interesting/distinctive enough to warrant a bit more asking around. Maybe seek out some framebuilders and get their opinions.